# Finding Cartesian/symmetric form using $x,y$ and $z$

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, multivariate-polynomial

I am having trouble figuring out how to write a Cartesian equation for the following:
\begin{align}
x & = t\\
y & = 2t\\
z & = \cos t
\end{align}
with $0\le t \le 4\pi$. I would know how to do it if I was given only two equation, but having a third one with a trigonometric function is throwing me off.

Answer (score 0):

Since $x=t$, for $x \in [0,4\pi]$ you get
$$
\begin{cases}
y = 2x \\
z = \cos x. 
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: My bad, it was supposed to be 4π, but I accidently wrote 2π.

Comment: That does not change anything.